# $t(x)=\prod \limits _{k=1}^{2n}\sin \left (\dfrac{x-x_k}{2}\right )$ a trigonometric polynomial proof

Tags: numerical-methods

> Show that, for real $x_1,\ldots ,x_{2n}$,the function:$$t(x)=\prod \limits _{k=1}^{2n}\sin \left (\frac{x-x_k}{2}\right )$$is a trigonometric polynomial$$\frac{1}{2}a_0+\sum \limits _{j=1}^na_j\cos (jx)+b_j\sin (jx)$$with real coefficients $a_j,b_j$.

I was thinking in using the De Moivre's formula, but I can't find how to build the transformation. Any idea is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Induction on $n$?

Comment: @SeewooLee how could u use it?

Comment: Trigonometric formulas like $\sin \alpha \sin \beta = -\frac{1}{2}(\cos(\alpha + \beta) - \cos(\alpha - \beta))$, $\sin\alpha \cos\beta =  \frac{1}{2}(\sin(\alpha + \beta) + \sin (\alpha - beta))$ would help you.